# Show all dates in range and show amount of rows on that day

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to have a query which shows all days of a certain period (for instance from 01/01/2017 - 12/01/2017) and then for every day I need to show the amount of rows inserted on that day grouped by the customer who inserted it.

So for instance I have this table:

```
+------------+------------+-----------+
| customerId |    Date    |  Message  |
+------------+------------+-----------+
|          1 | 01/01/2017 | Message 1 |
|          1 | 01/01/2017 | Message 2 |
|          1 | 01/01/2017 | Message 3 |
|          2 | 01/01/2017 | Message 1 |
|          2 | 01/01/2017 | Message 2 |
|          1 | 02/01/2017 | Message 3 |
|          1 | 02/01/2017 | Message 4 |
|          2 | 03/01/2017 | Message 3 |
+------------+------------+-----------+
```

The result should be this:

```
+------------+------------+----------+
|    Date    | customerId | messages |
+------------+------------+----------+
| 01/01/2017 |          1 |        3 |
| 01/01/2017 |          2 |        2 |
| 02/01/2017 |          1 |        2 |
| 02/01/2017 |          2 |        0 |
| 03/01/2017 |          1 |        0 |
| 03/01/2017 |          2 |        1 |
+------------+------------+----------+
```

I already have this query:

```
SELECT TRUNC (SYSDATE + ROWNUM, 'DD') as dt
FROM DUAL CONNECT BY ROWNUM < 12
```

Which gives me a table with the date range for x amount of days (in this case 12). I already tried joining my table with this DUAL table (LEFT JOIN and JOIN) but it doesn't give me the result I need.

Edit: I just found that I could use `CROSS JOIN` to show all dates.

Comment: i removed the mysql tag as the syntax looks like Oracle.

Comment: Oh yeah sorry it was suggested.

Comment: I just found out that I probably need a `CROSS JOIN`

Comment: do you have the dates table or you've to generate it?

Comment: I have to generate it. But I can use the query I listed in the question: `SELECT TRUNC (SYSDATE + ROWNUM, 'DD') as dt
FROM DUAL CONNECT BY ROWNUM < 12`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got it working:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT DAT.*, V.ID, V.NAME
     FROM (SELECT TRUNC ((SYSDATE - 22) + ROWNUM, 'DD') as dt
     FROM DUAL CONNECT BY ROWNUM <= 4) DAT CROSS JOIN (SELECT ID, NAME FROM ORGANISATIONS) V) DATES 
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT OGE_ID, TRUNC(REGISTRATIONDATE) AS roundday, COUNT(*) FROM ZAKEN GROUP BY TRUNC(REGISTRATIONDATE), OGE_ID) CASES 
ON DATES.DT = CASES.roundday AND DATES.ID = CASES.OGE_ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

From your table example:

```
select Date, customerId, count(messages) from tablename group by Date, customerId;
```

will give your desired result

Comment: That doesn't give me the dates which doesn't have results.